Published Apps not pushing update changes
I created an app 'ReachOut: Friend Tracker' and published it on playstore. After login the app was saving the data erroneously which led to app crashing, when I solved the error and pushed the changes again. It never shows the new update without the error after it has been solved successfully. Even the playstore version changes properly.
It's been a week now.
What I already did:-
1.Changed the versions
2.Used the same keystore
Can you help me out?
Updated changes never reflect the code changes

I'm not sure if this is a programming question.

Can you help where I can post my query?
